# Unity Android build - Failed to repackage resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, resources

I want to implement a google games leaderboard in my game, I'm currently trying some things out.
The problem is that I get a "Failed to re-package resources" error when I build the apk.

Here is the console log: http://pastebin.com/usayj7NJ

I tried the solution in the top answer of this post:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/834744/building-android-application-failed-re-package-res.html

So I went to Plugins/Android and there I didn't have a "res" folder, so I just created one, I also created the values folder inside it and lastly the version.xml file, but it didn't work.

I read on other posts that this error can be caused by duplicate copies of google play services, but I can't seem to find any.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Are you using play games api ? do u have manifest file inside Plugins/Android/"manifest.xml" ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the play games api. I have an AndroidManifest.xml in Plugins/Android

Comment: i hope you have configured the leaderboard in google play developer console..did you run any play games api samples?

Comment: I did configure the leaderboard in the developer console. It's my first time using play games and I'm trying some things out, but I can't fix this error

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I was using an outdated version of the admob plugin, that was probably interfering with the play games plugin.